# bash starts /bin/sh on docker:git

Tags: bash, docker

On my computer `bash` starts and lasts on `docker:git`.

```
~ # bash
bash-4.4# ps
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sh
   26 root       0:00 bash
   32 root       0:00 ps
bash-4.4# echo $0
bash
bash-4.4# echo $SHELL
/bin/ash
```

`ash` seems a bit uneasy but I'm able to run `#!/bin/bash` file so it's fine so far.

However, on Gitlab CI on gitlab.com, command `bash` doesn't return anything but it doesn't seem to keep running. Why is this?

```
$ apk add --update bash
$ bash
$ ps && pwd && echo $0 && echo $SHELL && ls /bin
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   10 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   25 root       0:00 ps
/builds/230s/industrial_calibration
/bin/sh

ash
base64
bash
bashbug
:
```

More detailed output on my computer:

```
$ lsb_release -a|grep Description
No LSB modules are available.
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
$ docker pull docker:git
$ docker images | grep -i docker
docker    git    5c58d1939c5d        10 days ago         152MB
$ docker run -it docker:git

~ # apk add --update bash
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
:
(10/10) Installing tar (1.29-r1)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r11.trigger
OK: 37 MiB in 31 packages
~ # bash
bash-4.4# ps
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sh
   26 root       0:00 bash
   32 root       0:00 ps
bash-4.4# echo $0
bash
bash-4.4# echo $SHELL
/bin/ash
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml` used (this fails at the last line as the passed file uses `bash` specific syntax):

```
image: docker:git
before_script:
  - apk add --update bash coreutils tar  # install industrial_ci depedencies
  - bash
  - git clone https://github.com/plusone-robotics/industrial_ci.git .ci_config -b gitlab_modularize
  - ps && pwd && echo $0 && echo $SHELL && ls /bin
  - source ./.ci_config/industrial_ci/src/tests/gitlab_module.sh
```

---

**UPDATE**: Sourcing bash-based file in `bash -c` indeed works, but it's probably not useful to me as what I really want is to use a function defined in that file and because `bash -c` line terminates and doesn't carry the context, the function won't be available in the later lines IMO.

```
- /bin/bash -c "source ./.ci_config/industrial_ci/src/tests/gitlab_module.sh"
- pass_sshkey_docker
```

Comment: could you try to run your command in bash dicrectly with `-c` option, so something like `/bin/bash -c "git clone... && ps && pwd"`

Comment: @MazelTov I've updated my post to answer to your comment.

Comment: another option might be to create own image, you will use `FROM docker:git` and then just install the bash and set the `ENTRYPOINT` to bash instead sh(or ash) and then use that image in your pipeline...

Comment: also with gitlab-ci i learnt to use `docker run -i` without the -t option so my command works and the exit code is detected... example: `docker run -i my_image /test_unit.sh`, and that is why i like the executor `docker:dind` :-)

Comment: `bash -c 'source foo; "$@"' _ some_function_in_foo arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 0):

```
image: alpine
before_script:
  - apk add --update bash coreutils tar
  - bash
  - echo smth
```

Now imagine your are the computer. You wait for each command to finish before executing the next one, you don't use the keyboard. So what do you do? Let's try it with alpine, substituting newline with `;`:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm alpine sh -c 'apk add --update bash; bash; echo smth'
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/6) Installing pkgconf (1.3.10-r0)
(2/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.0_p20171125-r0)
(3/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.0_p20171125-r0)
(4/6) Installing ncurses-libs (6.0_p20171125-r0)
(5/6) Installing readline (7.0.003-r0)
(6/6) Installing bash (4.4.19-r1)
Executing bash-4.4.19-r1.post-install
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r7.trigger
OK: 13 MiB in 17 packages
bash-4.4#
```

YOU DON'T TOUCH THE KEYBOARD. You can wait endlessly for the `bash-4.4#` line to disapear as bash will wait endlessly for you to type anything. The command `echo smth` will never execute, gitlab will timeout waiting for bash to end, the end.
Now if you want to execute something in alpine using bash using gitlab-ci i suggest doing it this way: create a executable script `ci-myscript.sh` that you git add&commit to your repo:

```
 $ cat ci-myscript.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 git clone https://github.com/plusone-robotics/industrial_ci.git .ci_config -b gitlab_modularize
 ps && pwd && echo $0 && echo $SHELL && ls /bin
 source ./.ci_config/industrial_ci/src/tests/gitlab_module.sh
```

The first line `#!/bin/bash` tells that shell should execute this script under `bash`. Now from your gitlab-ci you run:

```
image: docker:git
before_script:
  - apk add --update bash coreutils tar
  - ./ci-myscript-sh
```

Creating such scripts is actually a good workflow, because you can test the script locally on your computer before testing it in gitlab-ci.
The other option is to single call bash as suggested by @Mazel in comments:

```
image: docker:git
before_script:
  - apk add --update bash coreutils tar
  - bash -c 'git clone https://github.com/plusone-robotics/industrial_ci.git .ci_config -b gitlab_modularize; ps && pwd && echo $0 && echo $SHELL && ls /bin; source ./.ci_config/industrial_ci/src/tests/gitlab_module.sh'
```

That way you need to call everything in single line, because the next line won't have the same enviroment as the previous line.